# OAuthException #100 when creating custom object with facebook sharp SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Basically, I have a custom object inheriting from place.  I am creating a c# tool for creating the objects using the Facebook Sharp c# SDK located [here](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)  I am using an app access token when making these calls.

I've tried various approaches and variation within:

1. Here is a sample call that yeilds:

   ***(OAuthException - #100) (#100) The parameter object is required***

   ```
   _api.AccessToken = GetExtendedToken().Token;
   var postdata = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       //{"fb:app_id", "appId"},
       //{"type", "myapp:myobject"},
       {"url", resort.Url},
       {"title", resort.Name },
       {"image", resort.Image},
       {"video", resort.Video},
       {"description", resort.Description},
       {"place:location:latitude", lat},
       {"place:location:longitude", long}
   };
   var response = _api.Post("/app/objects/myapp:myobject", postdata);
   ```
2. if I uncomment the type parameter I get:

   ***(OAuthException - #2500) Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter***
3. If I add the type back in, and remove the type from the path, I get
   a response of ***true*** but this should be something like **id:
   23049820398092384**
4. If I remove the place objects, or if I remove place and type, or if
   I remove place but use the type and change the get path, I still get
   errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refactored a bit.  In this scenario I needed to assign the postdata information to an object as such below.  also needed to stop using facebooksharp, their api does weird stuff to the request.

```
    var obj = new
    {
        app_id = appId,
        type = app_name:object_type",
        url = Url,
        title = Name,
        image = Image,
        video = Video,
        description = Description
    };

    var vars = new NameValueCollection {{"object", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)}, {"format", "json"}, {"access_token", AppToken}};

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/"+ _appName + object_type;
    return HttpTools.Post(url, vars);
```